# Bash scripting: date -d won't accept my string format of hhmmss. I need a workaround

Tags: bash, datetime-format, time-format, string-to-datetime

I need a Bash script to accept 1 argument representing a time in *hhmmss* format, and from that derive a second time 3 minutes before that.

I've been trying to use `date -d`:

```
#! /bin/bash
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
TIME=$1
NEWTIME=`date -d "$DATE $TIME - 3 minutes" +%H%M%S`
echo $NEWTIME
```

In action:

```
$ ./myscript.sh 123456
invalid date `20141022 123456 - 3 minutes'
```

It seems the problem is with the 6 character time format because 4 characters (eg 1234) works.  The subtraction of the 3 minutes is not the problem because I get the same error when I remove it.

It has occurred to me I could parse the time into a more palatable format before sending it to `date`.  I tried inserting delimiters by adding this line:

```
TIME=${TIME:0:2}:${TIME:2:2}:${TIME:4:2}
```

It accepted that format but the answer to the `- 3 minutes` part was inexplicably very wrong (it subtracted 2 hours and 1 minute):

```
$ ./myscript.sh 123456
103356
```

Vexing.

It has also occurred to me that I might be able to provide `date` with an input format, like `strptime` which I'm familiar with from Python.  I've found references to `strptime` in the context of Bash but I've been unable to get it to do anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions on getting the *hhmmss* time-string to work?  Any help is much appreciated.

FYI: I'm trying to avoid changing the 6 character input format because that would involve changing other scripts as well as getting certain human users to alter long-entrenched habits.  I'm also trying to avoid outsourcing this task to another language.  (I could easily do this in Python).  I want a Bash solution to this problem, if there is one.

Comment: I think you hit on the correct answer with your delimiting. To get date to handle hhmmss time input it would seem you need to use hh:mm:ss but that hhmm is legal when "bare". The parsing oddity is certainly annoying and means you might need two calls to date for this.

Comment: The problem is with the `- 3 minutes` part. If I use your code that added the colons and leave that out, it works fine.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting.  But what is wrong with the `- 3 minutes` part?  It complies fully with what is in the documentation, as far as I can tell.  And it also works perfectly when given a time in hhmm format.

Comment: I don't know. It works when used by itself, but not when combined with a date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TIME=093000
TIME=${TIME:0:2}:${TIME:2:2}:${TIME:4:2}         # your line
date -d "2014-10-20 $TIME 3 mins ago" +%H%M%S
```

Output:

```
092700
```

Comment: Was I using the `- 3 minutes` form incorrectly?  The documentation uses that form.  I see no reason for it not working.  Bug?

Comment: @ibonyun: Sorry, I do not know.